# Getting an error: Objective function must return a scalar , while I try to minimize a function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to minimize a function and trying to calculate the value of `X` that gets the lowest value of the output `Y`. I am using `scipy` to calculate this. I wrote the following code for this, but I am getting an error that says:

```
ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def f(x):
    Y = ((x + 100) / 100)
    return Y


def apply_constraint(inputs):
    if(inputs[0] >= -1):
        return 0


my_constraints = ({'type': 'eq', "fun": apply_constraint})

min_result = minimize(f, [2,2,2], method="SLSQP", options={
                    'disp': False}, bounds=[(-2, 101),(-2, 101),(-2, 101)], constraints=my_constraints)

print("Minima found at: X = {}, Y = {}".format(min_result.x, min_result.fun))
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Your `Y` in `f(x)` is on `len` = `3`. It is an array, not a scalar. Replacing `return Y` by `return Y[0]` gives `Minima found at: X = [-2.  2.  2.], Y = 0.98`. I don't see why you are using these three values `[2,2,2]` and what is the use of `my_constraints`? You are not using it anywhere

Comment: @Bazingaa I could not understand the result. What does the X value `[-2. 2. 2.]` really mean? Isn't all the three values of `X` supposed to be equal? Also what does passing an array in `guess` really mean? I am trying to understand various arguments of `minimize`.

Comment: Since all the X values are supposed to be the same, why don't you just use `min_result = minimize(func, 2, method="SLSQP", options={'disp': False}, bounds=[(-2, 101)])`?

Comment: @Bazingaa I could definitely use that, but I was trying to understand by experimenting various combinations on `minimize`. What does passing multiple values to guess really mean?

Comment: All you have to do is to provide some single starting guess value. Passing several initial starting points for minimization doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: @Bazingaa The document suggests that you could pass multiple values https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html , so I am trying to reason why. Also `bounds` accepts an array to.

Comment: If you check the example where they use multiple bounds, the function to minimize also is 2-d where `x[0]` and `x[1]` are treated as separate variables. In your case, you are passing `[2,2,2]` to a single variable `x`.  For ex. If you replace your `Y` by `Y = ((x[0] + 100) / 100)  + ((x[1] + 100) / 100) + ((x[2] + 100) / 100)`, you get a `Minima found at: X = [-2. -2. -2.], Y = 2.94` which means optimum `x[0]` is -2, optimum `x[1]` is -2 and optimum `x[2]` is -2. Hope you got my point. Plugging in `-2` in your `y` now, you get 3*98/100 = 2.94

Comment: @Bazingaa Okay. So passing 3 values in the `guess` array and 3 in the `bounds` array would make sense in a 3-d function?

Comment: Exactly. That is my point.

Comment: @Bazingaa Okay. Had one more question. What does `constraints` attribute actually do? I could not understand this. The function `apply_constraint` returns `0` when the input is greater than `-1`. Would it mean that the value of X could only be greater than equal to `-1`?

Comment: @F.John: The constraint must be a smooth function whose _value_ is constrained to be (greater than or) equal to some constant.  It can’t just return yes or no, since that would give no hint as to where to go instead.